# Testing mobile and desktop versions of the same site with Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I have a site that completely differs on the front-end between the mobile and desktop versions.

You cannot scope steps when defining them on Cucumber, so I am stuck with two solutions (as I see):

- Write every step that conflicts with the other version, explicitly saying which version I am
- Set up a "background" which tells me what is my context, and change all the step definitions to check for this context

None of this seem optimal to me.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tags and hooks for this, tag each scenario/feature with the version of the site it tests:

```
@mobile
Scenario: Logging in on mobile
  Given I visit the login page

@desktop
Scenario: Logging in on desktop
  Given I visit the login page
```

Use some hooks to set a variable indicating the version of the site being tested:

```
Before '@mobile' do
  @version = :mobile
end

Before '@desktop' do
  @version = :desktop
end
```

Then in your steps:

```
Given /^I visit the login page$/ do
  if @version == :desktop
    # Desktop specific code
  elsif
    # Mobile specific code
  else
    raise "Don't know what to do!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a different solution but this is also a nice alternative.

Comment: Cool, it would be interesting if you added your solution as an answer to the question for when people find this question in future!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just did that!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a solution similar to Jon M.

For the concurring steps I made a "meta" step, that passes on to the correct context. Here is an example:

```
When /^I log in$/ do
  step %Q{I log in on #{@context}}
end
```

Then in another file (separated by context) I have:

```
When /^I log in on mobile$/ do
  # do stuff
end
```

To setup the context, I created a support module. Basically, it keeps the current context and also has a default one, that you can change with a step:

```
Given /^I am on the "(.*?)" version$/ do |version|
  @context = version
end
```

It's not exactly how I setup the context part, but you get the picture.

The advantage in this, is that I can have infinite contexts and this "meta" steps will pick them up. I also don't have bloated steps. Each step stays simple and only deals with it's own context logic.

The downside is that for each non-default context I have, I need a Background stating that I am on a different context.

I won't accept a right answer here, since there is no such thing. You can deal with it with different approaches and until now, there isn't even a best practice about this :)